# Strange compilation errors when compiling groovy traits

Tags: groovy, traits

I often encounter strange  compilation issues arising randomly when using traits in groovy. They sometimes go away by clearing caches, or when artificially forcing the users of these traits to recompile by adding an empty comment, but this error here, I can't shake, This is my trait:

```
trait SOAPClientErrorLogger {
    def withLogging(Closure soapCall) {
        try {
            soapCall()
        } catch (SOAPClientException e) {
            log.error("Failed to invoke SOAP endpoint:  ${e.request.url} \ndata:${new String(e.request.data)} \nResponse:${e.response?.statusCode}:${e.response?.contentAsString}")
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

causes the following error compiling (both in IDEA and running gradle independently):
`Error:Groovyc: Method '$_gc_computeOldVariables' is protected but should be public in trait 'com…SOAPClientErrorLogger'.`

This same error is printed for each trait that is part of my project
They compiled fine before.

Anyone has an idea how I should proceed? Or an explanation as to why traits are so delicate to use in a groovy project?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

These errors seem to appear when I include the groovy wrapper library around the functional java library:

'com.github.mperry:functionalgroovy-main:0.8'

Comment: Have you tried using static compilation `@CompileStatic` on the trait?

Comment: This trait will not compile statically because it accesses a non-declared member variable `log`.  Why do you think that this could matter?

Comment: It worked in command line with groovy 2.4.3 :-/

Comment: I'm also getting these errors when I started using the gcontracts library :(